# Spring Boot : Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am getting below error when executing my application. It says to create a bean of type HttpSecurity, "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration"

Please let me know if I need to provide any other details.

Git repo : https://github.com/anubhav8804602148/ARMSellers
branch : bug_http_missing_bean

Error

```
LOGBACK: No context given for c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@951885923

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2022-12-10 13:12:34.902  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] com.arm.seller.ARMSellersApplication     : Starting ARMSellersApplication on Anubhav with PID 12780 (D:\my_projects\AuthenticationDemo\target\classes started by Anubhav in D:\my_projects\AuthenticationDemo)
2022-12-10 13:12:34.904  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] com.arm.seller.ARMSellersApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-12-10 13:12:34.934  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Anubhav\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Anubhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Anubhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Anubhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/Anubhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Anubhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/Anubhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2022-12-10 13:12:34.935  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-12-10 13:12:34.935  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-12-10 13:12:35.365  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-10 13:12:35.457  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 86ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-10 13:12:35.712  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-12-10 13:12:35.890  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 10801 (http)
2022-12-10 13:12:35.896  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-10 13:12:35.896  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2022-12-10 13:12:36.103  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-10 13:12:36.145  WARN 12780 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-12-10 13:12:36.222  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-10 13:12:36.264  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
2022-12-10 13:12:36.344  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2022-12-10 13:12:36.407  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-10 13:12:36.634  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-10 13:12:36.647  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-12-10 13:12:37.182  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-12-10 13:12:37.186  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-10 13:12:37.502  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-12-10 13:12:37.510  WARN 12780 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authManager' defined in class path resource [com/arm/seller/configure/SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'authManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2022-12-10 13:12:37.511  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-10 13:12:37.513  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-12-10 13:12:37.518  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-12-10 13:12:37.519  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-10 13:12:37.526  INFO 12780 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-10 13:12:37.580 ERROR 12780 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method authManager in com.arm.seller.configure.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.blog.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>ARMSellers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ARMSellers</name>
    <description>A: Apparels, R: Residencies and M : Meal Sellers app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
             <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.arm.seller.configure;

import com.arm.seller.service.CustomAuthenticationProvider;
import com.arm.seller.service.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
        return authBuilder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder){
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
    

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf().disable()
//                .requiresChannel(channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/home").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/rolesManager").hasAuthority("ADMIN_CREATE")
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .usernameParameter("email")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this, since it is not needed

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
        return authBuilder.build();
    }
```

As you are already overriding the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder){
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```